# Single instance of script, but only with same arguments

Tags: shell-script, process, ps

I have this beautiful little code here that will exit from a script if there's another instance of it running:

```
single_instance(){
    if pidof -x "${0##*/}" -o %PPID >/dev/null; then
        exit 0
    fi
}
```

But what I'm looking for is a function that will exit only if the script has been **called with the same arguments**.

I know I could hack my way with a `cat | grep | awk | cut | sed | tac | sort | uniq` solution, but I wonder if there's a simple way of doing this with utilities like `pidof`, `ps`, etc.

How would you go about doing this?

Comment: Hmm, you would need to keep track of all the pids of running instances, and then check their command line through procfs (assuming they didn't change them somehow), if you have that available. Otherwise your launch script would need to also keep a copy of the command lines associated with each pid. And you need to check if parameters are given in a different order.

Comment: And this is where the trouble starts: how do you know how to split a command line in several parameters? Is the filename associated with the previous option toggle, or is it a parameter on its own? It depends on the application..

Comment: +1 to didierc's answer, but your deleted one also has potential -- check the output of `ps -o cmd= -p $PID` -- this is intended for use in code and will give you the executable name plus arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fn() { IFS='
';  set -- $(ps -o args= -C "${0##*/}")
    unset IFS
    [ $(($(printf $(printf %s\\n "$@" | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn)))) -gt 1 ] &&
        exit 0
}
```

This will `exit 0` if two or more `$0` processes are currently running that were invoked with the same arguments.

Comment: Thanks, @mikeserv! I don't know why, but `ps -o args= -C ${0##*/}` always returns empty.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior - Weird, I don't either... What is the name of `$0`?

Comment: `$(basename $0)` -- Or is that the same as `${0##*/}` ?

Comment: @goldilocks - maybe, but it shouldn't make any practical difference. I did just add `"quotes"` - it maybe there was `$IFS` in the name before and this should fix that. But otherwise I'm stumped as of now.

Comment: It returns empty if I run it as `bash scriptname`, which I generally do on tests, but not if I put it in `$PATH`. BTW, it exits even if it is the first instance.

Comment: I did this with an array: `bn=$(basename $0); IFS=$'\n'; array=$(ps -o cmd= -C $bn)` and that works, if it's any help.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior Hmm... I need to make it more explicit.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior - the `|` pipe processes were counting toward the overall invocation count. Sorry about that. So I split it out. I think it's fixed now. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, now it does!

Comment: @mikeserv I'll probably choose your answer if none simpler shows up, but remember that the script will `exit 1` if `errexit` is set and there's no other instance of the script, so I believe it is safer to use a full `if` statement.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior - what about your answer? I never use `errexit` - I always test everything. It really isn't as hard as it sounds. Like, do I have more than one positional parameter? `${2+:} echo no`. You can do most stuff like that. Anyway, you can `set +e` for the life of the  function if you want.

Comment: @mikeserv In mine the arguments could coincide with `" $$ "`, so it is not _100%_ safe!

Answer (score 3):

I came up with this after studying `man ps` and adding some code from @goldilocks. It does a good job in handling arguments with spaces, and also works if script is called as `bash scriptname`:

```
single_instance(){
    if ps -efww | grep "$(ps -o cmd= -p $$)$" | grep -vq " $$ "; then
        exit 0
    fi
}
```

Comment: This will always quit script if you call with arguments.

Comment: @Gnouc fixed now!

Comment: How about: `ps -wwNp $$ -ocmd= | grep -Fxq "$(ps -wwp $$ -ocmd=)" && exit 0`

Comment: @rici I like your command, but I couldn't figure out why it will exit many times, even if there is no instance of the script running.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior: Fascinating. It's a race condition; the first `ps` may encounter one of the other subprocesses in the cmd during the time between fork and exec. At that moment the subprocess still has the same commandline but it has a new pid. I don't know why your version doesn't exhibit the same race condition, or maybe it does but less frequently.

Comment: @rici It's unfortunate that this happens, because my code has the problem that the arguments could coincide with `" $$ "`, which is very unlikely to happen, but not impossible. `ps --version` returns `procps-ng version 3.3.3`

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

single_instance() {

   pid=$(pidof -x "${0##*/}" -o %PPID)

   if [[ $(xargs -0 < /proc/$pid/cmdline) == $@ ]]
   then
       echo QUITTING
       exit 1
   fi
}

single_instance $(xargs -0 < /proc/$$/cmdline)

while :
do
    sleep 10
done
```

Comment: `+1` nice handling of `/proc/$pid/cmdline` :)

Answer (score 2):

Using */proc*:

```
single_instance(){

   local tl=$(cat /proc/$$/cmdline)
   local l

   tl=${tl##*/}

   for pid in $(pidof -x "${0##*/}" -o %%PPID); do
        l=$(cat /proc/$pid/cmdline)
        if [ ${l##*/} = $tl ]; then
            echo "already running..."
            exit 0
        fi
    done
}
```

It does an exact comparison between command lines without the launch path (like you did in your script). The `/proc/*/cmdline` values don't have any space in them, so you can conpare them directly. If the parameter order changes though, it won't notice it.

Comment: Thanks, @didierc! It worked when I replaced your `pidof` command with mine above. I also found it funny that `/proc/$pid/cmdline` seems to remove all spaces, but this is enough already!

Comment: Yes, I was in the process of changing my script to take spaces in account, and when I got it working, I realised it wasn't necessary!